# android.permission.PHONE_CALL is added in manifest but still got permission error

Tags: android, permissions, call

I'm trying to use ACTION_CALL intent for calling a USSD code. I have added the android.permission.PHONE_CALL to the manifest file but it doesn't work and get the permission error exception. PS: as you see there are also permissions for GPS and INTERNET and they works fine.
Here are the codes:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
    String number = "*140*1";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number + encodedHash));           
    try{
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch(Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PHONE_CALL" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity .......
```

Comment: What is the exception? add logs here

Comment: The permission is `android.permission.CALL_PHONE`, not `android.permission.PHONE_CALL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misspelled the text, change to the following:
android.permission.CALL_PHONE

Comment: yeah, he posted during I was writing the response.

Comment: Which is what @MikeM said 5 minutes **before you**.

Comment: yeah, I know, but because I am the new comer here, when i clicked on the post, it shows up a "How to post a better answer", so spent sometime to go through it. that's why. Anyway, should I remove the answer then?

Comment: You're justified by the reading of the instructions. No, it's not necessary, since @MikeM didn't post it as an answer. And you can't unless you reach a certain reputation.

Comment: @DerGolem MikeM should post it as answer and not as comment! +1 for that

Comment: After all... +1 for posting it as an answer. So the OP can remove it from the UQQ.

Comment: @DerGolem Whoa! Jeez, I didn't mean to cause a ruckus here! I had voted to close the question as a typo. I was just trying to help the OP out at the same time. Answers in comments are fair game for anyone to post, as far as I'm concerned. No worries!

Comment: @MikeM. No worries, you were the first one answering correctly. All credits to you.

Comment: Thank you guys. My bad, but in writing the question! The problem was solved by deleting the .android folder and cleaning the project. These kind of problems makes me crazy. It's maybe another question, but my frequent job now is to: restarting the computer to solve the problem of identifying device, cleaning the project to solve Manifest file missing problem, and deleting .android folder for other issues!

Answer (score 1):

The permission for making phone calls is not spelled "android.permission.PHONE_CALL" its "android.permission.CALL_PHONE".
For more information visit Android Developer API document for Manifest permission.

[Android Manifest permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: Which is what @MikeM said.